# AJAX not running PHP result from a form connected to a file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay, this is a fairly simple thing to do and I have no idea what is going on.

I am new to PHP & jQuery so please go easy on me if there are any seriously obvious errors.

If you take a look at my HTML form for my login form...

**login.html**

```html
<p style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Login</b>
</p>
<p id="registerwelcome">Maybe you've already signed over your soul and want to dive straight in to continue searching for the best places to hang out? You know what to do...</p>
<p>
  <b>Username:</b>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="loginusername" id="loginusername" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <b>Password:</b>
  <br/>
  <input type="password" name="loginpassword" id="loginpassword" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login" />
</p>
```

...and here is my JavaScript file, the jQuery file is already loaded in the main document where all of this takes place, so there's no need to worry about offering advice about it not being included.

**usersystem.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#registercontent").on('click', '#register', function() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var confirmpassword = $("#confirmpassword").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var dataString = 'username1=' + username + '&password1=' + password + '&confirmpassword1=' + confirmpassword + '&email1=' + email;
    if (username == '' || password == '' || confirmpassword == '' || email == '') {
      alert("Please make sure you have filled in all the required fields.");
    } else if (password != confirmpassword) {
      alert("Passwords do not match.");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "files/php/register.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          document.getElementById("registercontent").innerHTML = result;
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
  $("#logincontent").on('click', '#login', function() {
    var loginusername = $("#loginusername").val();
    var loginpassword = $("#loginpassword").val();
    var dataString = 'loginusername=' + loginusername + '&loginpassword=' + loginpassword;
    if (loginusername == '' || loginpassword == '') {
      alert("You left the username or password field blank, oops.");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "files/php/login.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
          $("#content").html('<div class="exclusivetransparentboxleft"></div><div class="exclusivetransparentboxright"></div>');
          $('.exclusivetransparentboxleft').load('files/php/usercp.php');
          $("#navigation").html('<div id="navigationitem">Home</div><div id="navigationitem">About Us</div><div id="navigationitem">Support</div><div id="navigationitem">Add Review</div><div id="navigationitem">View Venues</div><div id="navigationitem">Book Venues</div>');
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

The result should display the user control panel by loading the page successfully, obviously it should then create a session through the PHP file with the users name so that we know whether they're logged in or not.

**login.php**

```html
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");
$loginusername = $_POST["loginusername"];
$loginpassword = $_POST["loginpassword"];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$loginusername AND password=$loginpassword");
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (password_verify($loginpassword, $row['password']))
{
    $_SESSION["logged"] = $loginusername;
 exit();
}else{
?>
<p style="font-size: 16px;">
    <b>Incorrect</b>
</p>
<p>We're sorry to report that the username and password combination you entered does not exist, if you would like to try to login again then please click <a href="javascript:loadContent('#logincontent','login.html');">here.</a></b></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

It's gotten the stage where I've played around with this so much I have no idea what's happening anymore.

Just like to add that I am extremely appreciative for any help given, this has been wracking my brain for 2 days now!

Once again, thanks for any help given.

Comment: so, after successful login, what should get display ?

Comment: Once login is successful, the content box should change entirely, loading up two new divs and resulting in one of the divs having a page loaded within it also using AJAX, it's displayed in the result section but it should also be creating a session through the PHP file to store the users name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$loginusername = $_POST["loginusername"];
$loginpassword = $_POST["loginpassword"];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$loginusername AND password=$loginpassword");
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (password_verify($loginpassword, $row['password']))
```

You search for a user that has the value entered in the password input in its database record. That won't succeed because you probably hash his password before writing it to the database.

So change the query to:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$loginusername");
```

Then check the password with password verify.

Be aware that your code is insecure. Use parameterized queries to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: For some reason, the problem still persists, no matter what is entered into the database, it will not set the session for the username and seems to let the user in regardless of what password is entered...

Although, I did originally have the query parameterized but took them out to solve the problem first.

Thanks for your help though, just didn't do the trick!

Comment: What does the call to login.php return? You can either alert the result in javascript or look at the request in the network tab of the F12 dev tools in your browser.

Comment: If I set it to alert, it's giving me the incorrect username or password message; but yet it's still changing everything to suggest the user is logged in, I'm guessing because it is showing the success result.

I suspect I'd have to set the jQuery to activate in the PHP file? Then set the script to then run the jQuery from there if the user successfully logs in?

Comment: You have to check the return value of the PHP file and only inject the user panel if the login was successful. The succeed method you use in jQuery just tells you that the request to login.php succeeded, it does not tell you, that the user logged in successfully.